# Python Anaconda proxy ".condarc" file

Tags: python, proxy, anaconda

*I am beginner in Python, slightly more familiar with R. My background is about mathematics rather than programming, then everything related with core system, etc. usually sounds strange for me !*

**I am working behind a corporate firewall and I recently solved the issue for R & Rstudio by creating a ".Renviron" file that includes the proxy identification + my user name and password. 
I am fighting to do the same for Python & Anaconda by creating a ".condarc" file!**

Here are 2 articles from Stackoverflow that I looked at before:
- [Python Anaconda Proxy Setup via .condarc file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883371/python-anaconda-proxy-setup-via-condarc-file-on-windows)
- [Unable to update conda packages behind corporate firewall. Updated .condarc file, proxy settings still it is asking for Proxy user name and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778507/unable-to-update-conda-packages-behind-corporate-firewall-updated-condarc-file)
unfortunately it is not really helping me and finally it is still not working on my computer. I guess there is only a small change to do on my computer, but which one?..

Besides, I'd like to mention that the following is working in a Python notebook:

```
import requests  
proxies = {  
    'http': 'http://myname:mypwd@proxy-blabla.fr:8080',  
    'https': 'https://myname:mypwd@proxy-blabla.fr:8080'  
}  
requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)  
#Note: "myname" is indeed something like "abc\\def"
```

But I have to write it in each script + it is not allowing me to run any script like urllib.request.urlopen(), etc. then to re-use codes that I can find in stackoverflow, etc.

Any suggestion ? why the following ".condarc" does not "work" ?

```
channels:  
  - r  
  - defaults  
proxy_servers:  
    http: http://myname:mypwd@proxy-blabla.fr:8080  
    https: https://myname:mypwd@proxy-blabla.fr:8080
```

Note : I am using :
- conda 4.1.6
- python 3.5.2
- os : Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: it might be a bit late, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883371/python-anaconda-proxy-setup-via-condarc-file-on-windows you can skip the channels and you need to url-encode all letters in myname and mypwd.